# Django Channels 2.0: call Consumer's channel by its name

Tags: django, django-views, django-channels

I am trying to upgrade my code from django-channels 1.1.8 to 2.0.0

So, I just want to perform a very simple async background task, and can not figure out how to call consumer by its name like in 1.1.8

Following example does not work (prints nothing):

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, ChannelNameRouter

from tasks.consumers import LongTask

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    'channel': ChannelNameRouter({
        'long-task': LongTask
    }),

})
```

**consumers.py**

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer

class LongTask(SyncConsumer):

    def long_task(self, message):
        print(message)
```

**views.py**

```
def perform_long_task(request):

    channel_layer.send('long-task', {
        'type': "long.task",
        'text': 'Hey!'
    })
```

---

I guess something wrong here `channel_layer.send('long-task', {...})`

Big thx

Answer (score 0):

So based on your implementation, you are on the right track. You forgot to run the following

`python manage.py runworker long-task`

The print message would display there. More information is provided here https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worker.html

Answer (score 0):

If after runworker, it's still not working, see below.

The manual says:

> Also remember that if you are sending the event from a synchronous environment, you have to use the asgiref.sync.async_to_sync wrapper as specified in channel layers.

So you should try this in your view:

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)("long-task", {"type": "long.task", "text": 'Hey!'})
```